# What are the possible meanings of the Words "The coming of the Son of Man" as used in scripture?

Tags: son-of-man

What are the possible meanings of the Words "The coming of the Son of Man" as used in the scriptures?

Mat 10:23, Berean Literal Bible

> And whenever they persecute you in one city, flee to the next. For truly I say to you, you shall not have completed the cities of Israel until the Son of Man comes.

Note: I am not asking for the meaning of the passage put above. I only cited it for a reference of one of its ambiguous usage.

Comment: NT concept of "Son of Man" is based on [1 Enoch 69]. - Did you want comparative analysis to Navi of Tanakh (like Ezekiel) who was also the Ben-Adam?

Answer (score 1):

We should all agree that according to the *New Testment*, he is the Son of G'd, but this implies his aspect of godliness, not his human aspect. For fulfilling this role, we should say **Son of Man**, this is, he was a human person, with desires, fears and so on. According to the trinity ✠, as being the **Second Person**, and G'd, he is fully human and fully divine. In **Mark 10:45**, we see his human way to deal with things, using the term **Son of Man**:

> 45 For even the Son of Man did not come to be served, but to serve,
> and to give his life as a ransom for many.” (NIV)

In jewish tradition it's known to refer to **Son of ...** as *Bnei Israel* or even *Bnei Noach*, in this case, **Bnei Adam**. Well, that's not hard to comprehend. As a jewish he is also very comic, as we read in **Mark 14:62**:

> 62 “I am,” said Jesus. “And you will see the **Son of Man** sitting at the
> right hand of the Mighty One and coming on the clouds of heaven.” (NIV)

In this, he answers the question if he is the **Son of G'd**.

*Appendix: in the jewish philosophy, Jesus is considered a kaballist, a Rabbi with mystical wisdom, and then, when he uses these words, he uses in this sense, meaning that MAN (a request) will have an answer given from heavens, that's why, he makes an equivalence with being the Son of Man and being the Son of God, which in my point of view seems to be plausible with the idea of Trinity*.

Comment: Did you mean to write 'cosmic' instead of 'comic'? The Q does not seem to ask about what the title 'Son of Man' means, but in what sense / senses does this one 'come' i.e. appear again / return. I may have misunderstood the Q myself, of course.

Comment: I meant comic anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The coming of the Son of Man, Jesus Christ, is constant theme of the NT as the brief survey in the appendix below shows.  This is sometimes referred to (technically) as the "Great Eschaton", from the Greet ἔσχατος (eschatos) = "Last".

This "second coming" of Jesus (ie, following His first coming as a baby in Bethlehem) is associated with many other things such as the great final judgement, our glorification, etc, as listed in the appendix below.

**APPENDIX - Coming of the Son of Man**

The New Testament writers looked forward to a future day when Jesus would return, and this theme appears many times in the NT.  This return of the Jesus is associated with the final judgement in various ways.

- Matt 16:27 - For the Son of Man will come in His Father’s glory with His angels, and then He will repay each one according to what he has done.
- Matt 24:30, 31 - At that time the sign of the Son of Man will appear in heaven,c and all the tribes of the earth will mourn. They will see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven, with power and great glory.d And He will send out His angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather His elect from the four winds, from one end of the heavens to the other.
- Matt 24:42 -  Therefore keep watch, because you do not know the day on which your Lord will come.
- Matt 26:64 - “You have said it yourself,” Jesus answered. “But I say to all of you, from now on you will see the Son of Man sitting at the right hand of Powerj and coming on the clouds of heaven.”
- Mark 8:38 - If anyone is ashamed of Me and My words in this adulterous and sinful generation, the Son of Man will also be ashamed of him when He comes in His Father’s glory with the holy angels.”
- Mark 13:26, 27 - At that time they will see the Son of Man coming in the clouds with great power and glory.d And He will send out the angels to gather His elect from the four winds, from the ends of the earth to the ends of heaven.
- Luke 21:25-28 - There will be signs in the sun and moon and stars, and on the earth dismay among the nations, bewildered by the roaring of the sea and the surging of the waves. Men will faint from fear and anxiety over what is coming upon the earth, for the powers of the heavens will be shaken. At that time they will see the Son of Man coming in a cloud with power and great glory.b When these things begin to happen, stand up and lift up your heads, because your redemption is drawing near.”
- John 14:3 - And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come back and welcome you into My presence, so that you also may be where I am.
- Acts 1:11 - “Men of Galilee,” they said, “why do you stand here looking into the sky? This same Jesus, who has been taken from you into heaven, will come back in the same way you have seen Him go into heaven.”
- 1 Cor 1:7 - Therefore you do not lack any spiritual gift as you eagerly await the revelation of our Lord Jesus Christ.
- 1 Cor 4:5 - Therefore judge nothing before the appointed time; wait until the Lord comes. He will bring to light what is hidden in darkness and will expose the motives of men’s hearts. At that time each will receive his praise from God.
- 1 Cor 11:26 - For as often as you eat this bread and drink this cup, you proclaim the Lord’s death until He comes.
- Phil 3:20 - But our citizenship is in heaven, and we eagerly await a Savior from there, the Lord Jesus Christ, who, by the power that enables Him to subject all things to Himself, will transform our lowly bodies to be like His glorious body.
- 1 Thess 1:9, 10 - For they themselves report what kind of welcome you gave us, and how you turned to God from idols to serve the living and true God and to await His Son from heaven, whom He raised from the dead—Jesus our deliverer from the coming wrath.
- 1 Thess 3:13 - so that He may establish your hearts in blamelessness and holiness before our God and Father at the coming of our Lord Jesus with all His saints. Amen.
- 1 Thess 4:15-17 - By the word of the Lord, we declare to you that we who are alive and remain until the coming of the Lord will by no means precede those who have fallen asleep. For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a loud command, with the voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God, and the dead in Christ will be the first to rise. After that, we who are alive and remain will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And so we will always be with the Lord.
- 1 Thess 5:23 - Now may the God of peace Himself sanctify you completely, and may your entire spirit, soul, and body be kept blamelessa at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ.
- 2 Thess 2:1, 2, 8 - Now concerning the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and our being gathered together to Him, we ask you, brothers, not to be easily disconcerted or alarmed by any spirit or message or letter seeming to be from us, alleging that the Day of the Lord has already come. ... And then the lawless one will be revealed, whom the Lord Jesus will slay with the breath of His mouth and annihilate by the majesty of His arrival.
- Titus 2:12, 13 - It instructs us to renounce ungodliness and worldly passions, and to live sensible, upright, and godly lives in the present age, as we await the blessed hope and glorious appearance of our great God and Savior Jesus Christ.
- 2 Tim 4:8 - From now on there is laid up for me the crown of righteousness, which the Lord, the righteous Judge, will award to me on that day—and not only to me, but to all who crave His appearing.
- Heb 9:27, 28 - Just as man is appointed to die once, and after that to face judgment, so also Christ was offered once to bear the sins of many; and **He will appear a second time**, not to bear sin, but to bring salvation to those who eagerly await Him.
- Heb 10:25, 37 - Let us not neglect meeting together, as some have made a habit, but let us encourage one another, and all the more as you see the Day approaching. ... For, “In just a little while, He who is coming will come and will not delay.
- James 5:7-9 - Be patient, then, brothers, until the Lord’s coming. See how the farmer awaits the precious fruit of the soil—how patient he is for the fall and spring rains. You, too, be patient and strengthen your hearts, because the Lord’s coming is near. Do not complain about one another, brothers, so that you will not be judged. Look, the Judge is standing at the door!
- 1 Peter 2:12 - Conduct yourselves with such honor among the Gentiles that, though they slander you as evildoers, they may see your good deeds and glorify God on the day He visits us.
- 2 Peter 3:8-10 - Beloved, do not let this one thing escape your notice: With the Lord a day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years are like a day. The Lord is not slow in keeping His promise as some understand slowness, but is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish but everyone to come to repentance. But the Day of the Lord will come like a thief. The heavens will disappear with a roar, the elements will be destroyed by fire, and the earth and its works will be laid bare.
- 1 John 2:28 - And now, little children, remain in Christ, so that when He appears, we may be confident and unashamed before Him at His coming.
- 1 John 3:2, 3 - Beloved, we are now children of God, and what we will be has not yet been revealed. We know that when Christ appears,a we will be like Him, for we will see Him as He is. And everyone who has this hope in Him purifies himself, just as Christ is pure.

Comment: Great Take.  But the Emphasis of my Question is largely on Eschaton.  How many times did the son of Man come.  Maybe I should rephrase the question or ask another fresh one since we have answers already

Comment: @FaithMendel - see Heb 9:27, 28 - Just as man is appointed to die once, and after that to face judgment, so also Christ was offered once to bear the sins of many; and He will appear a **second time**, not to bear sin, but to bring salvation to those who eagerly await Him.  (quoted above)

Comment: Good but there are multiple times the son of man is to come in his power and glory, in mat 16 some will not taste death till they see the son of man come in glory

Answer (score 1):

OP asked "What are the possible meanings of the Words "The coming of the Son of Man" as used in the scriptures?"

One possible meaning of the word the son of man is reflecting on who He is and what his goal is.

Looking back at the first scriptures that mention the son of man we see He came from the seed  of  the woman that was promised.

> He says to the serpent, "And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your seed and her seed; He shall bruise you on the head, and you shall bruise him on the heel" (Gen. 3:15).

It also states that the seed would bruise the head of the serpent, the shining one, the devil, and all the other names that is given to the prince of the air, the god of this evil eon.

The cross was the turning point in history for all mankind as well as the whole entire universe.  The Son  of Man is now coming back to keep the promise and finish what he started with the seed of the serpent.  The Son of Man comes back with judgment and people will probably realize he is also the Son of God through what he does on earth.

Answer (score 1):

**What are the possible meanings of the Words "The coming of the Son of Man" as used in scripture?**

**SON OF MAN:**

Jesus applied this expression to himself on many occasions and one of the possible reasons is with regards to the fulfillment of the prophecy at Daniel 7:13-14.  Daniel saw the son of man gaining access to the  Ancient of Days and to "him was given ruling authority, honor, and sovereignty.  All peoples, nations, and language groups were serving him." [ Part  Vs 14a] And his kingdom will last forever.

Daniel 7:13-14 NASB

The Son of Man Presented

> 13 “I kept looking in the night visions, And behold, with the clouds
> of heaven One like a son of man was coming, And He came up to the
> Ancient of Days And was presented before Him.  14 And to Him was given
> dominion,  Honor, and [a]a kingdom,  So that all the peoples, nations,
> and populations of all [b]languages  Might serve Him. His dominion is
> an everlasting dominion Which will not pass away; And His kingdom is
> one Which will not be destroyed.

"The Ancient of Days," God,  is the one who gives Jesus the Kingdom and dominion over the earth. This is the kingdom for which Jesus taught his followers to pray.

Mathew 6:9-10 NASB

> “Pray, then, in this way:  ‘Our Father, who is in heaven,  Hallowed
> be Your name. 10 Your kingdom come. Your will be done, [On earth as it
> is in heaven.

Comment: Ozzie, Excellent answer.  Up voted.

Comment: Sherrie: It is encouraging Tks